# Issue with sys.exc_info() within a function returns None tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function which open an access database. When it fails, it throws an exception with a pywintypes_error message like :

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Une exception s\u2019est produite.', (0, None, 'La base de données est déjà ouverte.', None, -1, -2146820421), None)
```

I want to catch this message with sys.exc_info(), but it doesn't work within my function : it returns None.

Here's my function:

```
def drop_user(user):
    global dbpath

    with open("login_hash.txt", 'r+') as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()
        for lines in data:
            if user not in lines:
                fp.write('')
            fp.truncate()

    try:
        print("Access running...")
        access = win32com.client.Dispatch('Access.Application')
        access.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbpath)
        acDb = access.CurrentDb()
        access.Visible = False
        access.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("DROP USER " + user + ";")
        kill_access()
        del access
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", user + " a bien été ajouté.")
    except (pywintypes.com_error):
        pattern = r'"(.*?)"'
        m = re.search(pattern, str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
        messagebox.showinfo("Erreur", m.group().strip('"').replace('\xa0', ''))
        kill_access()
        del access
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`exc_info()[1]` is the exception instance, which you can get much more easily using the `as <name>` part of the except clause, ie:

```
try:
    your_code_here()
except pywintypes.com_error as exc:
    # here `exc` is the exception instance
```

Then you can get the params that were passed to the exception using `exc.args`.

You may also want to learn about string formatting operations, ie:

```
print("this is a {} with {}".format("format string", "placeholders"))
```